# Django updates model instead of inserting when calling save()

Tags: python-3.x, django

Im trying to make a web app that has per user models. When logging in as a user with no current models it creates a new model for that user. The problem is that instead of inserting a new model it updates the existing model. The model has 3 fields, user, name and value. upon logging in the logic checks to see if there is model values with the users name in it and if there isn't then it creates a new model, or should. But currently it just updates all rows to associate them with the user that just logged in.
This is my code for creation of a new model which is called when a user that has no model associated with it logs in and when a user wants to reset there model.

EDIT 1: added model format

```
#if there is no models associated with user/ recreate the model is called
Board.object.filter(user=user).delete();
#create the new model
for row in page_data.get("rows"):
    for name, value in row.items():
        Board(user=user, name=name, value=value).save()


class Board(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 2, primary_key=True)
    value = models.CharField(max_length = 6)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("user", "name", "value"))
```

Comment: Can you share your `Board` model definition in your `models.py`?

Comment: @BernardoDuarte did

Comment: `name` is the **primary key** of your model (for some reason I don't know. I would advice not to make such columns as the primary key, a name implies that it can be changed so it is not a good primary key). When you write `Board(user=user, name=name, value=value).save()` Django sees that the object has a value assigned to the pk so it first tries to update the table where the pk is the given value (Here this update succeeds) if the update fails then Django saves a new entry to the database.